# En Apigee me aparecen 2 errores cuando intento usar la herramienta para hacer debugging, alguien ha podidio solucionarlo?

Tags: gcp

Contexto:

En Apigee cree un API Proxy que cuando se le hace una peticion responde con un HolaMundo!!

Este API Proxy esta Desplegado en un ambiente de evaluacion y funciona perfectamente cuando le hago peticiones con Postman.

Problema:

Cuando quiero usar la herramienta para hacer Debbugging y ver como se ejecuto el flujo, me salen los errores que se muestran en la imagen.

-" Error fetching debug transactions
list debug session transactions failed for debug session {thinking-case-395316 eval Raimundo-hello-Copia 1 c756d323-d4ce-4681-91f3-2fa40099d742}. "

-" List debug session transaction error."

[image: Errores que aparecen al intentar usar la herramienta de debugging]

Intentos para resolverlo:

- Buscar informacion en google (no consegui nada util para este problema).
- Utilizar una version nueva.
- Undeployed and Deployed.
- Crear una copia del API Proxy y utilizar esta en vez del original.
- Trabajar en la version mas reciente de Apigee (Aca no da el error pero tampoco registra ninguna peticion)

Si alguien sabe que mas podria hacer o como solucionarlo? les agradeceria profundamente.